# spark-shell --master yarn stuck in ACCEPTED state

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I tried many solutions but none of them is working.

1. Added property **yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage** to yarn-site.xml with value as **98.5**

2.added below property to yarn-site.xml
         
   yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark_shuffle.class                                     org.apache.spark.network.yarn.YarnShuffleService

3. Added property in spark-defaults.conf **spark.yarn.jars=hdfs://localhost:50010/users/spark/jars/*.jar**